# Error showing while loading "dplyr" package in R.

Tags: r

```
ibrary("dplyr")
```

Gives the following errors.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘rlang.so’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘$.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘$.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘$<-.quosures’, ‘$<-.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[.quosures’, ‘[.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[.rlang_envs’, ‘[.stack’, ‘[<-.quosures’, ‘[[.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘[[.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘[[<-.quosures’, ‘[[<-.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘Math.quosure’, ‘Ops.quosure’, ‘Summary.quosure’, ‘as.character.quosure’, ‘as.list.quosures’, ‘c.quosures’, ‘c.rlang_envs’, ‘conditionMessage.rlang_error’, ‘format.rlang_trace’, ‘length.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘length.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘mean.quosure’, ‘median.quosure’, ‘names.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘names.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘print.frame’, ‘print.quosure’, ‘print.quosures’, ‘print.rlang_data_pronoun’, ‘print.rlang_envs’, ‘print.rlang_error’, ‘print.rlang_fake_data_pronoun’, ‘print.rlang_lambda_function’, ‘print.rlang_trace’, ‘print.rlang_zap’, ‘ [... truncated]
```

But while specify the lib path as  `.libPaths( "/usr/lib/R/library/"  )` and then loading library will load the `dplyr` package and does not gives error. 
I would like to know actually what is the issue behind this.
Also install.package("dplyr") on R console is also not working.
It gives error like:

```
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘rlang.so’ not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dplyr’
```

Comment: Try installing package `rlang`. It seems to be missing.

Comment: Since it works when you specify the library, you probably have multiple libraries. Use `.libPaths()` to see them.

Comment: @anotherfred I had that with Python once, had two instances of Anaconda installed on two different paths, and I would install modules in one library and run Python from the other. Was a nightmare till I figured out what was going on. Your comment should be SOP first steps for dealing with any errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the "dplyr" package. This issue is due to the the latest rlang installed on a version of R for which binaries are no longer built....

1. Try restarting your R-Studio
2. https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ : Install Suitable versions in the link according 
   to your system requirements and update the R on your device
3. Try updating your R to the latest version

**Alternate Answer:**

Would recommend waiting until the binaries are available on CRAN for dplyr > 0.7.4 before making a breaking change that requires 0.7.6

install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘ ...
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
dplyr 0.7.4 0.7.7 TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: